# How to check for presence of a glyph?

Tags: vimrc, unicode

I run vim under various terminals, supporting different sets of Unicode glyphs.
While I can make vimrc settings depend on the value of `TERM`, this is slightly error prone, since updates of glyph support may go unnoticed. Is there a way to detect the presence of a glyph for a code point at runtime? For example with a function like this:

```
if has_glyph_for_code_point(10007)
  let g:ale_sign_error = '✗'
else
  let g:ale_sign_error = 'X'
endif
```

I tried `:help glyph` but it came up empty. Searching glyph in the help file mbyte.txt did not reveal anything in this direction.

Comment: this will be hard if not impossible, since vim does not know whether your terminal can display that font. And even for gvim, vim does not know whether your font actually has a glyph for that particular code point (because those could also be replaced by your font system dynamically)

Comment: If you use Linux you can use `fc-cat` to list the glyps that are in a given font, but you need to know which font your terminal uses and Vim doesn't really know that (but you can hard-code it). Using `fc-cat` also requires some work; I have a [basic script over here](https://github.com/arp242/uni/issues/1#issuecomment-660529482), but it's not perfect: in particular, I don't know how to check for glyps that consist of multiple codepoints (common in emojis), although you probably don't need that in your case.

Comment: Terminals using fallback fonts make it really hard to say for certain if something will render correct other than actually checking it :-/ For example I have my terminal set to `DejaVu Sans Mono`, but it will render many emojis from `Noto Color Emoji` as Xft selects that as a fallback font automatically. Different terminals use different libraries/logic, it depends on what's installed on the system, etc. I think this is basically impossible with the current state of things outside of other than launching a terminal, make it render the glyphs, and somehow checking if it rendered correct

Comment: And I can't really think of a way to do that either (which is ugly anyway, slow, won't work over ssh, etc). It's a good question, but unless I'm  missing something I'm afraid the answer is "you can't" :-(

Comment: @MartinTournoij Thanks for the detailed analysis. And then there's the observation, that not everything's an X11 terminal, like true console terminals, which is what I'm primarily looking for. X11 has such an abundance of fonts with comprehensive Unicode support that I don't bother. But my FreeBSD console, lying that it's an XTERM, bugs me no end :-)

Comment: There may be a small possibility to check. Suppose you add that glyph to your tabline `:set tabline=a showtabline=2` then you can capture what vim is seeing using `:let char=nr2char(screenchar(1,1))` and then compare against the actual codepoint